# How to list flavor VSI?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

What is the correct way to list the flavor for a VSI ?
Services like https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/ or https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/ have **supplementalCreateObjectOptions** which include ***flavorKeyName*** but I have been unable to use this,e.g ...mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,primaryIpAddress,primaryBackendIpAddress,type[name],transientGuestFlag,*supplementalCreateObjectOptions[flavorKeyName]*]" ...

Any advice could be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To know which flavor was used you can use the following rest call:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/11112222/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem[orderItem[preset]]]
```

I will return something like this:

```
"preset": {
                "description": "C1.1x1x25",
                "id": 293,
                "isActive": "1",
                "keyName": "C1_1X1X25",
                "name": "C1.1x1x25",
                "packageId": 835
            }
```

On the other hand, if you want to know which are the available flavors to order, you can use the [getCreateObjectOptions](https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions) method. See https://softlayer.github.io/article/vsiflavors/

Another way is through the method [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getActivePresets](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getActivePresets)

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/835/getActivePresets?objectMask=mask[computeGroup]
```

Comment: I updated my answer, it is possible to know which flavor was used to create the vsi